# How to add sqlite-jdbc jar in netbeans java desktop application while creating a installation setup file?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, installation

I have created a desktop application in netbeans IDE using `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2` jar and I am using `sqlite-jdbc.jar` library to save and retrieve the user data.

I am trying to make a installation file using clickteam install creator software or any other setup installation softwares but I dont know how to add `sqlite-jdbc jar` and some supportive  jars in the installation setup file.